# Initialising custom control both programmatically and from NIB

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, awakefromnib

I am writing a custom UI control, and am curious as to the standard practices around initialisation (particularly dependance on the control's delegate).  Like most controls, my control relies on the delegate to provide important information about how to render itself.

When the control is used from within a NIB, the `initWithCoder:` and `awakeFromNib` methods are correctly called and the delegate is nicely set up through the `IBOutlet`.  `awakeFromNib` calls a secondary method called `setupControl` which interacts with the delegate to set up my control.  Life's good!

However, when I create the control manually using `initWithFrame:`, obviously `awakeFromNib` is never called.  I am curious how other developers deal with supporting both IB and programmatic control creation.  I can see a couple of techniques for supporting the programmatic case:

- Force the developer to call `initWithFrame:`, followed by `setDelegate:`, followed by `setupControl`.  Not too onerous, but does expose the internal workings of my control (ie. they have to know about `setupControl`)
- Modify the `initWithFrame:` method to take the delegate as well.  This does encapsulate the inner workings a bit more, however, I am not sure that this is a particularly commonly used idiom (and it seems that manipulating subviews based on delegate responses is something that is normally deferred until a bit later in the view's lifecycle, rather than in the initialiser)
- Override the `setDelegate:` accessor to call the `setupControl` method.  Not a big fan of this, as it smacks of programming by side-effect.

Just thought I'd throw it out there to see what techniques I have overlooked.  Thoughts?

Thanks.
Craig

Answer (score 0):

First :
`-awakeFromNib` is automaticaly sent to controls once the NIB is fully loaded. That means that once the entire UI encapsulated in NIB is loaded Cocoa send `-awakeFromNib` to all UI components. The only reason it send this after loading is to avoid nil IBOutlet. 
Normaly if you add controls programmatically it's done after NIB unpacking and after all UI items are loaded (assuming you connect IBOutlet to your custom control). So there is no potential issue calling `-awakeFromNib` at the end of your `-initWithFrame:` method.

And : 
Everyone expect calling `-setDelegate:` when creating control programmatically. `-initWithFrame:` + `-setDelegate:` isn't to much in order to get a functional control created I think ;)

Comment: However, when you say there is no issue calling `awakeFromNib` from `initWithFrame:`, in the programmatic world the delegate won't be set via the `IBOutlet`.  It would be set manually in code - which is OK, but it would happen **after** `initWithFrame:` is called, which would mean that `initWithFrame:` can't reliably call `awakeFromNib` because it relies on the delegate being set.  It is this chicken/egg dilemma I am wrestling with.

Comment: As far as I understand your control rely on its delegate in its init and setup phase ? A delegate is optional and couldn't have to be required in order to initialize anything. You have a design issue here.